# How can I create a webpage with Django that displays two different queries?

Tags: python, django

For my Django project I decided to make a mock news website.  I created a class for the various news articles.  I made one of the variables “type” to designate whether the article was a news story or a podcast.  I then created two templates: news.html and podcasts.html.  Then, in views.py, I created a function that returns only the news stories for news.html and another function that returns only the podcasts for podcasts.html.

```
def allArticles(request):
    articles = Article.objects.filter(type="news").order_by("-date")
    return render(request, 'article/allArticles.html', {'articles': articles})

def podcasts(request):
    articles = Article.objects.filter(type="pod").order_by("-date")
    return render(request, 'article/podcasts.html', {'articles': articles})
```

I am trying to create a third page with two sections, one that displays news stories and the other will display podcasts.  I cannot just call the entire database because it will not be separated into the proper sections and there are other types of articles besides news stories and podcasts.
I tried combining the code of news.html and podcasts.html into one html file, however it will only return one of the two.  I also tried using snippets, it returned just the news articles twice.
I feel like the solution is somewhere in the URL patters.  Its like each path will only trigger one view so if I try to add another it is simply ignored.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.allArticles, name='allArticles'),
    path('<int:blog_id>/', views.articlePage, name='articlePage'),
    path('contributors/', views.contributors, name='contributors'),
    path('podcasts/', views.podcasts, name='podcasts'),
    path('<int:blog_id>/', views.podcastPage, name='podcastPage'),
]
```

Well, I thought typing this out might help me figure out what is going but alas I still need help.
Ultimately, what I am trying to figure out is how can I create a webpage with Django that displays two different queries from the same database.  I think I could restructure the models to make this easier, but I am trying to work with what I have. I am really just looking for guidance or someone to point me to the documentation that might address these issues.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your `urlpatterns` you have a `blog_id` parameter, but that is not included in the view.

Comment: Add a new url pattern for each new view. Add code in the new view to select articles and code to select podcasts. Create new view template and feed it with both articles and podcasts in the render call context dict. Access them inside the template. This is all very similar to what you already have for the other two views.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 2 functions, each with one variable; I needed one function with two variables. I added a variable called podcasts to the allArticles function and passed it into the context.

```
def allArticles(request):
    articles = Article.objects.filter(type="news").order_by("-date")
    podcasts = Article.objects.filter(type="news").order_by("-date")

    return render(request, 'article/allArticles.html', {'articles': articles, 'podcasts ': podcasts})
```